# Example of Joining Tables in Azure mobile services

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am new to azure mobile services.

As given in the [documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#TSQL) to join two tables .Here is the code.

```
mssql.query('SELECT t.text, t.complete, p.description FROM ToDoItem as t INNER JOIN Priority as p ON t.priority = p.number', {
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
    });
```

Result :

```
{ text: 'Take out the trash', complete: false, description: 'Critical'}
```

Obviously the results will be written to logs.

**So how will i get the result back at my client.?** 
What lines should i replace with **console.log(results);**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, because some scripts have both a request and response passed in, while others only have access to the request.

If this is within an API script, use

```
response.send(200, results);
```

If this is within a table script, use

```
request.respond(200, results);
```

Comment: As you pointed out, i tried a custom logic by creating an api.

Then i ran into some [problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924955/mclient-invokeapi-wrong-constructor-in-azure-mobile-services-android-sdk) while accessing it.

Can you pls help me on that?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924955/mclient-invokeapi-wrong-constructor-in-azure-mobile-services-android-sdk