# mClient.invokeApi wrong constructor in Azure-mobile-services android SDK and is not compiling

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Here is the snippet from [documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-call-custom-api/) azure

```
ListenableFuture<MarkAllResult> result = mClient.invokeApi( "completeAll2", MarkAllResult.class ); 

Futures.addCallback(result, new FutureCallback<MarkAllResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
        createAndShowDialog((Exception) exc, "Error");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(MarkAllResult result) {
        createAndShowDialog(result.getCount() + " item(s) marked as complete.", "Completed Items");
        refreshItemsFromTable();    
    }
});
```

}

This code can not be compiled,because there is no available Contructor for `mClient.invokeApi(String,Class)`.

I am new to azure.Can you please point out what went wrong? Or is there a problem with Android Azure SDK(V1.1.5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is now fixed  in Azure Mobile Android SDK V2.0.Got an official mail from Azure.

Comment: Where is SDK v2.0? The Azure website keeps pointing me to 1.1.5